# when running tests in django and PostgreSQL DB can't create database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, postgresql

I'm having a problem with running unit tests in django while using ElephantSQL,
when running command 
`python manage.py runserver` everything works just fine,

I'm able to connect to the server without any problem
but when running the command `python manage.py test`

I'm getting this error below:

````
C:\Users\Sman9\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\siteid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Djang
  warnings.warn(
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database


Creating test database for alias 'default'...
C:\Users\Sman9\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py:323: RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running 
tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the first PostgreSQL database instead.

  warnings.warn(
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database```
````

my databases setting in settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '####',
        'USER': '#####',
        'PASSWORD': '#############',
        'HOST': 'chunee.db.elephantsql.com',
        'PORT':'',
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have granted all required privileges to a user you have created for managing your database.

Using *psql* you can do so with the following command:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;
```

Additionally, you ought to have *psycopg2* installed for the postgres DB to pair with Django.

In a terminal execute the following:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: That didn't helped, maybe there is something i'm doing wrong
when you referring to mydb you mean to 'NAME' in my settings
and myuser as the 'USER' in my settings, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. What OS are you using by the way? Is it Linux or Windows?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: I use the psycopg2 engine in my own projects when working with postgres. In other words: 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'

Comment: that didn't help either...

Comment: My last recommendation for you is to check out this tutorial:

https://djangocentral.com/using-postgresql-with-django/

It helped me set up my Postgres DB and pair it with Django. You can skip the Linux part. The tutorial is pretty straight-forward and is easy to follow. Good luck!